# Looping through different types of posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a feed of images, videos, and text-posts using the same model. 
For an image post I have an image column, for text a body field, and for videos a url. I have separate partials for each type of post. Right now I'm looping through the posts like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<% if post.image.present? %>
  <%= render 'image_post' %>
<% elsif post.body.present? %>
  <%= render 'text_post' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'video_post' %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

It starts to get messy if I add any more types of posts. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, say I wanted to loop through just the video-posts. Can I loop though posts only with video_url present instead of doing this?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<% if post.video_url.present? %>
 <%= render 'video_post' %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a great reason to learn single table inheritence: http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/.  You're talking about 'types' of posts.  That is a clear indicator in OO design that you need to classify your objects as such.  Once you do that, this problem will be vastly simplified.

Comment: Hey Joe, I looked into this and agree it's the better way but for my particular project using one model is much easier and quicker (and temporary). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a mothod to you model to return the type of post

```
def type
  return "image" if image.present?
  return "text" if body.present?
  return "video"
end
```

In your view

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render "#{post.type}_post" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: type is kinda a reserved method name i think, cause it's used for STI in active record.

Comment: Simple solution. Thanks :)